# Error while compiling At MAcOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 with sml Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78

Tags: macos, list, sml

I am getting below error while compiling List.filter in below code

fun only_capitals(xs) =

List.filter (fn x => Char.isUpper(String.sub(x, 0))) xs

uncaught exception Io [Io: openIn failed on "/Users/jhr/Work/smlnj/osx-dist/smlnj.dst/sml.boot.x86-unix/smlnj/basis/.cm/x86-unix/basis.cm", No such file or directory]

raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71

../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11

../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55

../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:292.17-292.20

I am able to run other sml code.When I added this function with List.filter the error comes

Uninstall and install sml again